# FireDAC: Saving Time to SQLite DB

Tags: sqlite, delphi, time, firedac

I'm new to FireDAC and have a problem. I want to read and write a SQLite database with FireDAC in Delphi XE7. Most what I tried worked, but I have a problem with saving a TTime to the SQLite DB.

This works:

```
FDQuery1.Fields[0].AsString := EdName.Text;
```

This doesn't:

```
FDQuery1.Fields[1].Value := TeTime.Time; // TeTime = TTimeEdit (FMX)
```

Why? The first field is a "REAL" and the second one is a "NUMERIC" as explained here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Thanks,
LuMa

Comment: What's the exact error that the compiler tells you? Since you didn't provide us the error message, I'm only assuming your code won't compile (I've never used SQLite or FireDAC). When you don't provide this information, people like me who never use your combination of third-party tools can't answer. But with that simple error message, I just might be able to answer your question.

Comment: Create your SQLite time field as `TIME`, not as `NUMERIC` ([`here is FireDAC mapping`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Mapping_SQLite_to_FireDAC_Data_Types)). Then you can comfortably use `AsTime` or  `AsDateTime` casting.

Comment: @JerryDodge: There is no error message, thats the problem. The Value of the Field is just set to 0, when I use the code above. However, reading works:

    SeTime.Text := FDQuery1.Fields[1].AsString;

Comment: @TLama: Oh sorry, I didn't knew that, I was using these datatypes: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: No need to excuse :) We're all learning. Guys from DA-SOFT made our lives easier and if you're going to use your DB just in Delphi apps., I would just follow that way. Type safety that you gain by that is priceless.

Comment: @TLama: One last question. I created my Table/DB using TFDCommand, which worked (SQLite Commands). How can I do this with the TFDQuery at runtime? I cant compile this code:

    with FDQuery1.FieldDefs do
    begin
      Clear;
      Add('Year', dtInt32);
      { ... }
      end;

I get an error: "incompatible types: 'TFieldType' and 'TFDDataType'". I know why I get it, but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Like [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/Ssc78KHx) e.g.

Comment: Ah okay... thanks... You were faster then I edited. Now I get it... Thank you :)

Comment: Sure, you are right :) Post it as an answer again so I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the same environment to test, so the results might differ for you, but in Delphi XE3 with an older version of AnyDAC I ran this simple test:

```
ADQuery.Close;
ADQuery.SQL.Text := 'CREATE TABLE MyTable (Col NUMERIC)';
ADQuery.ExecSQL;

ADQuery.Close;
ADQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO MyTable (Col) VALUES (:Val)';
ADQuery.Params[0].Value := TTime(EncodeTime(1, 2, 3, 4));
ADQuery.ExecSQL;

ADQuery.Close;
ADQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Col FROM MyTable';
ADQuery.Open;
```

The result was that the fetched table field was of type `ftLargeint` and its value was 0. So you've just lost your value with this code. FireDAC fortunately offers you a better approach. You can create a table with a custom `TIME` field type like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Col TIME)
```

FireDAC internally maps such data type to a `dtTime` field type (it is described in [`this topic`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Mapping_SQLite_to_FireDAC_Data_Types)), so you can then natively access such field as being a real time field, like e.g.:

```
ADQuery.Close;
ADQuery.SQL.Text := 'CREATE TABLE MyTable (Col TIME)';
ADQuery.ExecSQL;

ADQuery.Close;
ADQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO MyTable (Col) VALUES (:Val)';
ADQuery.Params[0].AsTime := TTime(EncodeTime(1, 2, 3, 4));
ADQuery.ExecSQL;

ADQuery.Close;
ADQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Col FROM MyTable';
ADQuery.Open;

ShowMessage(FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss.zzz', ADQuery.Fields[0].AsDateTime));
```